# 3 column layout wordpress (3 posts on a page)

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress, multiple-columns

My client wants to have his news page with 3 columns and 3 posts on the page.

Each column has a title name, date, the excerpt and read more function.

Like this: http://rikvandoorn.nl/nieuws_pagina.jpg

Cause my PHP knowledge isn't that good, i was looking for some tutorials to create the 3 column page. But al those tutorials are outdated, in lack of information or they don't seem to work that well.

And the "leave a reply" can be moved to the single.php.

So i hope some of you can provide me some help.

This is my current content.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="aside">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- .aside -->

        <footer class="entry-meta">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <div class="comments-link">
                <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .comments-link -->
            <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like? Are you simply asking how to style the page like the image you linked to?

Comment: Styling the page doesn't seem That hard. What im looking for is the php script that is needed for creating that layout ( in functions.php) so every time a new post is added, only the layout is updating the content. With the possibilitie of multiple pages

Comment: Check [this search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bpost+%2Bcolumns+%2Blayout).

Answer (score 0):

Set up the wordpress [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="aside">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- .aside -->
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </article><!-- #post -->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

and then in the admin go to  Settings > General > Reading - select 3 in 'Blog pages show at most'